# Need information regarding the German Visa

Tags: germany

I am new to this community and would like your help with some of my queries.

So, here is my current situation. I am in India and have an offer letter from a German organization, and while they are ready to assist with the documentation, I have to process the visa on my own. I am expected to join there in Jan '24.

I have a spouse who is looking for a job and may join me after 4-6 months of my moving to Germany as a dependent. Assuming if he is not able to secure a job in Germany by the time i move, which visa are we supposed to apply for (P.S.- i am eligible for a Blue Card). And what are the formalities we need to perform after landing there.

Thanks in advance.

Preeti

Comment: This might help you select the appropriate visa https://digital.diplo.de/navigator/en/visa What has your own research so far revealed?

Answer (score 0):

you need to obtain a national (long-term) visa for employment/Blue Card from the competent German embassy.
https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/aussenpolitik/laenderinformationen

With this, you may enter Germany and start working immediately. With your Blue Card, your spouse may join you right away and search employment here.

--> If your spouse will apply for family reunion, you should submit your applications together !!!

It is no problem if they join you only a couple of months later, but the authority may check everything in one go. Separated applications lead to long waiting periods for the spouse.

Find more info about German visa here:
https://www.make-it-in-germany.com/en/visa-residence/types/eu-blue-card

(I don't check this website often and won't be available for another query.)

All the best for your relocation   :-)
Marion